# Binding a Windows client to Open Directory

Tags: windows, mac-osx, mac, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

Is it possible to bind Windows clients (to be specific Windows 8) to OS X Open Directory? The server is running OS X Yosemite.

I have not yet found any resources that give a clear answer about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with server versions after OS X Server Snow Leopard. Since the first release of the 'simple' server in OS X Lion, binding Windows clients to OS X Server is not possible anymore.

For authentication a client such as pGina can be used though, however it is not officially supported.